# Using Intro.js and jquery.cookie to show intro only on first view of each url

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-cookie, intro.js

I am using `intro.js` functionality across 3 different urls. I have limited it to show to users only the first time they load a page with:

```
unless $.cookie("firstview")? introJs().start()
$.cookie "firstview", "firstSet", expires: 365
```

But the one cookie prevents all subsequent urls from showing their `intro.js` for the first time. I tried:

```
unless $.cookie("page1")?
introJs(".page1").start()
$.cookie "page1", "firstSet", expires: 365, page: "/page1"

unless $.cookie("page2")?
introJs(".page2").start()
$.cookie "page2", "firstSet", expires: 365, page: "/page2"
```

But still only the first page will show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy to implement.

First, you should show the introduction to user and then set a cookie to browser upon `introJs.onexit()` callback ([see here](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js#introjsonexitprovidedcallback)), and when the user visited your page again, you can check the cookie to prevent showing the introduction again.